# Get current language in template

Tags: theming, 8, i18n-l10n

In Drupal 7 the current language is a global variable we can access with

```
global $language;
$langcode = $language->language;
```

I want to know how can we access the current language in a Twig file in Drupal 8 (in `page--front.html.twig` for example)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found my answer and post it here so maybe it helps others later.

First, in `MYTHEME.theme`:

**In Drupal 8.2 language got added to page the variables in [template_preprocess_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/8.2.x). But in my current version 8.1 it didn't exist so I added it with:**

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

  $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
  $vars['language'] = $language;
}
```

Then in my Twig file I use `{{ language }}`. Also I can get the language name with `{{ language.getName() }}`.

**Update**

After Drupal 8.2  a global variable `language` exists and now there's no more need to add it first.

```
{% if language.getId() == 'en' %}
  Do something
{% else %}
  Do something else
{% endif %}
```

*Update*
Thanks @Lucas for his comment

on Drupal > *8.7.5*

```
{% if language.getId() == 'en' %} should be {% if language == 'en' %}
```

Comment: Does not work. Drupal 8.3.7 here and `{{ dump(language) }}` gives me `null`. Note that I am in a twig in a module and not a theme.

Comment: @GuillaumeBois I'm having the same issue, `language` variable is accessible inside the theme templates but not in my custom module template. Could you find anything?

Comment: This simply does not work when trying to access the variable in the TWIG template. Works fine in the preprocess though.

Comment: Works in 8.5, just use {{ language.getId() }} in page.html.twig to print the language id

Comment: {% if language.getId() == 'en' %} should be {% if language == 'en' %} (Drupal 8.7.5)

Comment: @Lukas thanks, I've updated the answer by adding your notice.

Comment: This doesn't depend on Drupal version 8.7.5, the confusing part is that this answers overwrites the language object set in core with a string value. If you want to pass the id as string to the template, then use a different variable name, so that existing code still works.

Comment: Is not $vars['language'], is $variables['language']

Comment: @xstean, it's just a variable name, you can name it whatever you want as the hook input parameter. :)

Comment: @Yuseferi no, if you set $vars the variable language wont be passed to its respective template, it needs to be $variables, the var you can change is "language" cause is internal of course. I spent some really dump minutes trying to figure out why your first example wasn't working and yeah.. that $vars name was the detail

Comment: Yuseferi's answer above is better if you add that to mytheme_preprocess() (drop the _page). Then {{ language }} is available in all templates, not just the page tpls.

Answer (score 13):

On Drupal version 8.2.3 the `language` variable is already available in Twig templates. A usage example is this:

```
{% if language.getId() == 'en' %}
  Do something
{% else %}
  Do something else
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Doesnt look like it.

Comment: From @Yusef's answer
following is missing..

 function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

  $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
  $vars['language'] = $language;
}

Answer (score 9):

`{{ language }}` works but **only in `page` context**.

The example of this question(`page--front.html.twig`) happens to be a working one.

I tried in 8.7.6 with Xdebug. When called from somewhere other than `page.html.twig` it will returns a `null` instead of `{Drupal\Core\Language\Language}`

I think that's why some people report it working but others not. You might use it under `node.html.twig` or something. In this case you still need to provide that under preprocess() function of your theme.

Comment: Hi, welcome to drupal . have to  seen `function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

  $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
  $vars['language'] = $language;
}` on my answer?

Answer (score 6):

In page.html.twig and Drupal 8.7.6, I had to use:

`{% if language.id == 'en' %}` or `{{ language.id == 'en' ? 'active' : 'not-active' }}`

Other suggestions did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to display the language to the user in the user native language, so I was trying to display "Français" instead of "French" and this was the answer if it might help someone:

Inside a preprocess function:

```
    // Get the current content language in native form.
    $language_id = \Drupal::languageManager->getCurrentLanguage('language_content')->getId();
    $native_language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getNativeLanguages()[$language_id];
    $variables['current_language_name'] = $native_language->getName();
```

Inside a twig template:

```
{{ current_language_name }}
```