# Change language of a JS element when language has been changed from Drupal language switcher?

Tags: 8, javascript, i18n-l10n

First of all, sorry for the really confusing title, but I have no idea how to make it more reader friendly.
On my website, there are three languages: English, Finnish and Swedish. The user can change between these languages from the default Drupal language switcher.
Now the key part of the website comes from an API that I think is in JS. That JS element has its own language changing parameter.

> src="//www.websiteofapi.com/alpportal/oa_head.js?proj=api-of-our-company&key=api-key-goes-here&lang=sv&leaflet_gshim=1">

So in order to change the language of the JS element I would need to change that "lang=" part to what language I want.
I have that script with the address to the API in my page.html.twig file to make the API call to work all across the site.

Is there a way to change the lang=sv to lang=en and lang=fi when the user changes the language through Druapl language switcher?

From the companys API support they said:

> you have different pages for different languages:
>   website.fi/drupal/ (englisch)
>   website.fi/drupal/sv 
>   website.fi/drupal/fi 
>   This means that you should have a different script tag for each of these
>   paths. I guess Drupal allows that with help of a language variable
>   that is accessible in your page template. (But I really know little
>   about Drupal, so that's just a guess)

I am sorry for a long and confusing post, but it is really crucial to get this to work and I am losing my mind.
PS! I am really new to Drupal.

Comment: How is the JS being added to the page? https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme

Answer (score 0):

Something like this is what you're looking for I think.

```
theme_js_alter($js) {
  $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
  foreach ($js as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($value['data'], 'www.websiteofapi.com/alpportal/oa_head.js') !== 0) {
      $value['data'] = "//www.websiteofapi.com/alpportal/oa_head.js?proj=api-of-our-company&key=api-key-goes-here&lang=$language&leaflet_gshim=1"
    }
  }
}
```

Also see [Get current language in template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204289/get-current-language-in-template)

Comment: Thanks! But where should I put this piece of code?