# Check the active language

Tags: nodes, 9

I'm sorry for my bad English.
In my node.html.twig I have two layouts for two groups of languages.

1. English, Ukrainian and Bulgarian
2. Arabic, Farsi, Urdu
   I can't check with twig which is the active language to load one of the two layouts.
   I tried this but it didn't work.
   Thanks a lot if anyone can help me

```
{% if language.getId() == 'en' or 'uk' or 'bg' or 'ru' %}

    
        {{ content.field_mt_srv_body }}
        {{ content.field_sp_working_hours }}
        {{ content.field_sp_additional_information }}
        {{ content.field_mt_srv_video }}
    
    
         {{ content.field_sp_street_view }}
     
       {{ content.field_sp_city }}
       {{ content.field_sp_address }}
       {{ content.field_sp_email }}
       {{ content.field_field_sp_phone }}
       {{ content.field_sp_languages }}
       {{ content.field_mt_srv_tags }}
       {{ content.field_sp_website }}
       {{ content.field_sp_facebook }}     
      
    

{% else %}


    

        {{ content.field_mt_srv_body }}
        {{ content.field_sp_working_hours }}
        {{ content.field_sp_additional_information }}
        {{ content.field_mt_srv_video }}
        
    
         {{ content.field_sp_street_view }}
     
       {{ content.field_sp_city }}
       {{ content.field_sp_address }}
       {{ content.field_sp_email }}
       {{ content.field_field_sp_phone }}
       {{ content.field_sp_languages }}
       {{ content.field_mt_srv_tags }}
       {{ content.field_sp_website }}
       {{ content.field_sp_facebook }}     
      
    
   
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get this working in Twig

```
{% if language.getId() == 'en' or 'uk' or 'bg' or 'ru' %}
```

you have to define the variable `language` in a preprocess hook:

*mytheme.theme* or *mymodule.module*

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for node templates.
 */
function mytheme/mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $variables['language'] = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage();
}
```

The only template where this variable is predefined is the page template, so that you don't need the preprocess hook. See this core preprocess hook: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/

Answer (score -1):

In Drupal 8.5.7 and upwards a global variable 'language' exists that can be called directly in twig like example below.

```
{% if language == 'en' %}
```

See this resource [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204289/get-current-language-in-template)

Comment: This is incorrect, there is no global language in templates. It was only added to `page.html.twig`, but not other templates likes `node.html.twig`